# Duplicate lines with postgres window functions

Tags: postgresql, psql

The postgres documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) talks about window functions.

In their example:

```
SELECT salary, sum(salary) OVER (ORDER BY salary) FROM empsalary;
```

duplicates are handled as follows:

```
 salary |  sum  
--------+-------
   3500 |  3500
   3900 |  7400
   4200 | 11600
   4500 | 16100
   4800 | 25700 <-- notice duplicate rows have the same value
   4800 | 25700 <-- SAME AS ABOVE
   5000 | 30700
   5200 | 41100 <-- same as next line
   5200 | 41100 <--
   6000 | 47100
(10 rows)
```

How do you do the same thing making it so that duplicate rows are NOT given the same value?  In other words, I would like this table to look as follows:

```
 salary |  sum  
--------+-------
   3500 |  3500
   3900 |  7400
   4200 | 11600
   4500 | 16100
   4800 | 20900 <-- not the same as the next line
   4800 | 25700 <-- 
   5000 | 30700
   5200 | 35900 <-- not the same as the next line
   5200 | 41100 <--
   6000 | 47100
(10 rows)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `rows` in the frame clause in instead of the default `range`

```
select
    salary,
    sum(salary) over (
        order by salary
        rows unbounded preceding
    )
from empsalary
;
 salary |  sum  
--------+-------
   3500 |  3500
   3900 |  7400
   4200 | 11600
   4500 | 16100
   4800 | 20900
   4800 | 25700
   5000 | 30700
   5200 | 35900
   5200 | 41100
   6000 | 47100
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS